# VBA Chart Second Data Series

Tags: excel, vba

I've got some code that I wrote a few years back now, that would create a bar chart in one tab, based on data in another tab. I've now been tasked with displaying the same chart but with a second data series.

I have tried multiple ways, but have been unable to get this to work. I was wondering if anyone could look at the code below and point me in the right direction.

```
With Sheets("DynamicCharts")
    LastRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    Set Rng1 = .Range("B2:B" & LastRow & ", D2:D" & LastRow)
    ShName = .Name
End With
With Sheets("Live Data").ChartObjects("County").Chart
    .SetSourceData Source:=Rng1
    .FullSeriesCollection(1).Name = "='" & ShName & "'!$C$1"                     
    .FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = "='" & ShName & "'!$C$2:$C$" & LastRow
    .FullSeriesCollection(2).Name = "='" & ShName & "'!$D$1"
    .FullSeriesCollection(2).Values = "='" & ShName & "'!$D$2:$D$" & LastRow     
    .FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = "='" & ShName & "'!$B$2:$B$" & LastRow    
End With
```

Rows 10 and 11, .FullSeriesCollection(2) are the rows I've added, hoping that would add my second data series. However, I just get a debug message saying "Parameter not valid".

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Think I managed to work it out for those that are looking to achieve the same results

```
With Sheets("DynamicCharts")
    LastRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    Set Rng1 = .Range("B2:B" & LastRow & ", D2:D" & LastRow)
    ShName = .Name
End With
With Sheets("Live Data").ChartObjects("County").Chart
    .SetSourceData Source:=Rng1
    .FullSeriesCollection(1).Name = "='" & ShName & "'!$C$1"                     
    .FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = "='" & ShName & "'!$C$2:$C$" & LastRow    
    .FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = "='" & ShName & "'!$B$2:$B$" & LastRow
    .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    .FullSeriesCollection(2).Name = "='" & ShName & "'!$D$1"
    .FullSeriesCollection(2).Values = "='" & ShName & "'!$D$2:$D$" & LastRow
    .FullSeriesCollection(2).XValues = "='" & ShName & "'!$B$2:$B$" & LastRow   
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

I am thankful for sharing the code, I am thinking of making a for-loop which includes new series (new columns) to the right of existing ones, kind of like what you did, but for several graphs instead of just one.

I guess I will be using a "if-statement" for if there already exists a series (e.g. yours 1 and 2), so it can skip those (in case you have formatted them later and they are overwritten with new ones...).

The tricky part I struggle with is how to refer to column and row of a range into a formula. So instead of writing:

`.FullSeriesCollection(2).Values = "='" & ShName & "'!$D$2:$D$" & LastRow`

I would rather write something like:

`For i = 1 to "Columns_in_Range"`

`.FullSeriesCollection(i).Values = "='" & ShName & "'!$...## (D) => substitute with column(i) ##...$6:$D$" & LastRow`

I have here highlighted that I want to substitute the letter with a formula which then will work in a for-loop.

Regards Hallvard Skrede